# SQL Server Docker failing to start

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm running the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest docker image on unraid and after updating the container will no longer start correctly. Every time I start the container I get the following messages

> SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
> This container is running as user mssql.
> Your master database file is owned by mssql.
> To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
> 2021-08-11 20:56:34.92 Server Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_replicatedmaster.mdf' to '/masterDbDir/model_replicatedmaster.mdf'.

and then the container just stops. Here's the command I'm using to create the container

`docker run --name='MSSql' --net='bridge' -e TZ="Europe/London" -e HOST_OS="Unraid" -e 'ACCEPT_EULA'='Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD'='*********' -e 'MSSQL_MASTER_DATA_FILE'='/masterDbDir/master.mdf' -e 'MSSQL_DATA_DIR'='/dbData' -e 'MSSQL_PID'='Developer' -p '1433:1433/tcp' -v '/mnt/user/appdata/MsSql/masterDb/':'/masterDbDir':'rw' -v '/mnt/user/appdata/MsSql/data/':'/dbData':'rw' 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest' 102f33ac1e82bc126c0040c3a7aea05ae151a99a4ddc30cc671211206d2ed25a`

Comment: `docker create` creates a container but doesn't start it. Try `docker run` instead.

Comment: it's just because it's in unraid and uses a little gui to actually start the container. when it starts the container it basically does a run of the same command

Comment: Is `102f33ac...` an existing container ID? If so then it's already configured by the `docker run` command that created it, you just start it again with `docker start 102f33ac1e82bc126c0040c3a7aea05ae151a99a4ddc30cc671211206d2ed25a`